# Stuck in the definition of composite functions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It has been about 3-4 days that I have a started learning about calculus. Well I am pretty much unclear about the definition of composition of functions.

My textbooks defined the composition of functions in this manner.

Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ be two functions. Then the composition of $f$ and $g$, denoted by $g\circ f$,is defined as the function $g \circ f : A\to C$ given by
$$
           g \circ f(x)=g(f(x)),   \text{$x$ is an element of set $A$}.
$$
Well I am quite convinced by this definition and I can explain it to me by this example given in my textbook.

Find $g \circ f$ and $f \circ g$ if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are given by $f(x)=\cos x$ and $g(x)=3x^2$. Show that $g \circ f$ is not equal to $f \circ g$.

To start with, we have $g \circ f(x)=g(f(x))=g(\cos x) =3(\cos x)^2$. Similarly, $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))=f(3x^2)= \cos(3x^2)$. Note that $3(\cos x)^2$ is not equal to $\cos(3x^2)$,for $x=0$. Hence $g \circ f$  is not equal to $f \circ g$.

Now my main concern is by reading this definition and solving this example I just came to know how to solve problems. By reading the definition I know that $g \circ f(x) = g(f(x))$ and I can quite interpret it using sets by the fact that $f:A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ and $g \circ f: A \to C$.
But I cannot do the same for $f \circ g$: all I know about $f \circ g$ is that it is equal to $f \circ g(x) = f(g(x))$.

Please help me to interpret $f \circ g$ using sets and the equivalent definition that was given for $g \circ f$. I am a beginner so please explain me in quite great detail.

EDIT:- As per the answers and questions I think that I have not conveyed my problem properly.My main motive is to ask you about the domain and codomain of fog as per the sets given in the definitions.

Comment: Please use latex for your mathematical notation

Comment: I've edited about half, to give you a sense of how to use MathJax/LaTeX to make things more readable. You can do the rest by clicking "edit" below your question.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @JohnHughes Sorry for sabotaging your educational effort, I saw your comment only after editing.

Comment: Not a problem --- your edits appear to be similar to mine, except that you took the trouble to make "R" be boldfaced, as it should be. :)

Comment: I have edited please see the problem again.

Comment: @Shreyansh The question you edited is already answered in the answers.

Comment: Hi,Klaus I know but I want the domain and codomain that has been given acc to definition for sake of convenience so that I can grasp the concept easily.So can you tell me I am eagerly waiting for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be a little more general:

Let $f: A \to B$, $g: C \to D$ be functions.

The composition $g \circ f$ is defined when $B \subset C$ (or at least when Im$(f) \subset C$), as $g \circ f(x) \overset{definition}{=} g(f(x))$. From this definition it is clear why it must hold that Im$(f) \subset D$. Notice also that if Im$(f) \subset D$ then we can define this composition.

Next, do not be confused by the order: $f \circ g$ is similarly defined only when Im$(g) \subset A$.

An example can always help:

Let $f$ be the function on a set of ten people, that assigns to each person a hair color: $f:\{Person_1,...,Person_{10}\} \to \{Blonde, Brown, Black\}$.

Let $g$ be the function $g: \{1,...,10\} \to \{Person_1,...,Person_{10}\}$. $g(x) = person_x$. Then what is $f \circ g$? Is the other way defined?

Edit:

$g$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$, so the domain of $f \circ g$ is $\mathbb{R}$. The codomain is also $\mathbb{R}$ but can be restricted to $[-1,1]$ (why?)

Comment: I have edited please see the problem again. –

Comment: Hi Mariah your answer is correct but I want the domain and codomain that has been given acc to definition for sake of convenience so that I can grasp the concept easily.So can you tell me I am eagerly waiting for the responses.

Comment: @Shreyansh see edit, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

$f$ and $g$ need to be compatible in order to be composed, i.e. if $f: A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$, you can form $g \circ f$, but not $f \circ g$. For $f \circ g$ to make sense, the codomain of $g$ (which is $C$ here) must be contained in the domain of $f$ (which is $A$). Hence if $C \subseteq A$, you can form $f \circ g : B \to B$.

Comment: This is true if functions are looked at as sets of ordered pairs. But in certain branches of mathematics it is agreed that $f\circ g$ only makes sense iff the domain of $f$ *coincides* with the codomain of $g$, leading to a stronger condition: $C=A$ instead of $C\subseteq A$. If indeed $C\subseteq A$ but not $C=A$ then we can define a function $h:B\to A$ by stating that $h$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto g(x)$. Then according to the standards I mention $f\circ h$ is properly defined (and $f\circ g$ is not).

Comment: @drhab Right, I thought about that, but considered it a little bit too nitpicky for that level. After all, $f \circ g$ is used as a short-hand for $f \circ \iota \circ g$, where $\iota$ is the inclusion of $C$ into $A$.

Comment: I have edited please see the problem again. –

Answer (score 0):

f$\circ$g does not compose because of domain range conflict.

$g\circ f = \{ (a,c) \in A×C : exists. b \in B. with. (a,b) \in f, (b,c) \in g \}$

Comment: Hi, William you are correct but I want the domain and codomain that has been given acc to definition for sake of convenience so that I can grasp the concept easily.So can you tell me I am eagerly waiting for the responses.

Comment: @Shreyansh.  acc?

Comment: It is According